# How can overwrite the will_paginate urls? Will_paginate gem generate wrong url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, routes, will-paginate

I have a ruby on rails app and I use will_paginate to render my products from categories.

I have 3 routes for some action:

- /category1
- /category2
- /category3

When I am on /category2 or /category3 page, the will_paginate generate URLs with /category1?page=nr_page NOT for /category1 url.

From what I noticed, if I change the order of the routes, will_paginate will generate URLs with the first route from my routes file.

Comment: Can you add your routes file? Looks like problem might be there.

Comment: This are the routes in mai route.rb
    get '/themes' => 'category#show_category', as: :all_themes

    get '/templates' => 'category#show_category', as: :all_templates

    get '/design-system' => 'category#show_category', as: :all_design_system

Comment: How does your `show_category` action looks like?

Comment: I have this for will_paginate: @products = @products.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction} #{free}").paginate(:page => (page || 1), :per_page => 15)

Comment: In view I have this: 

    <%= will_paginate products,
                :class => "pagination pagination-azure pagination-no-border ".freeze,
       :previous_label => "«".freeze,
           :next_label => "»".freeze,
            :is_active => true
        %>

Comment: Ok, I already know, why it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: I wrote it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`will_paginate` uses `url_for` and `params` to figure out the path for pagination. According to what you said, your routes file looks something like this:

```rb
get '/themes' => 'category#show_category', as: :all_themes 
get '/templates' => 'category#show_category', as: :all_templates 
get '/design-system' => 'category#show_category', as: :all_design_system
```

When you add `<%= self.params.inspect %> to your view. you will see something like this (maybe with more params in the hash):

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"category", "action"=>"show_category"} permitted: false>
```

This means that will paginate takes these parameters and uses them in the [url_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for) method. The call looks like this:

```
url_for controller: 'category', action: 'show_category', page: 123
```

it doesn't see the current path in the browser, only the `controller` and `action` names. In this case it goes through all of the routes from the top until it finds first defined rule for given controller and action and takes the url from this rule. This means it will always use the URL for the first defined category in your list.

### Possible solutions

1. Define different actions for every category. It will work fine for you if you want to use it this way

```
get '/themes' => 'category#themes', as: :all_themes 
get '/templates' => 'category#templates', as: :all_templates 
get '/design-system' => 'category#design_system', as: :all_design_system
```

2. Define one route with the parameter

```
get '/category/:category' => 'category#show_category', as: 'show_category'
```

and then in your views or controller use following links:

```
  show_category_path(category: 'themes')
```

Just URLs will not look as nice as before.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This solution is not working for me, I need these routes for the SEO part. I have subcategories too and on /category/subcategory path will_paginate work good

Comment: In that case use the first suggested solution - create custom action for every category you have, do not share the `show_category` action for all of them.

Comment: Yes, the first one suggested should work. Let me try this.